# Best book(s) or online tutorial(s) to learn iOS development under Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, ios

I'm a fairly experienced programmer, though not as hardcore as some. :) I grew up on C years ago, dabbled in C++ a bit, and lately I'm into more script-based languages (PHP, JavaScript + jQuery, Perl). I messed around briefly with Xcode 3 and creating simple iPhone apps, and found it rather challenging (is it just me, or is Objective-C a bitch?!).

Anyway, with the release of Xcode 4, I'd love to get back into it and maybe give it another shot. What I'm looking for is a really well-organized book or books, or a web-based set of tutorials aimed towards users who are brand spankin' new to Xcode 4 and developing for iOS. Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know of any books that cover XCode 4, but I highly recommend "iPhone Programming, The Big Nerd Ranch Guide," by Joe Conway & Aaron Hillegass. Of the various Cocoa/iOS books I've taken a look at, this one pleases me the most.

Comment: Thanks! It does look really good, I'll check it out.

Comment: +1 for anything by Hillegass.

Answer (score 9):

Try Stanford's *Developing Applications for iOS
Fall 2010* course by Paul Hegarty.  It is currently available free via iTunes University.

Here is the [iTunes](http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/cs193p-student-final-projects/id395605774?i=90218598) link, and here is the [course page](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/) link.

#### Related Courses

- [Fall 2011](http://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/ipad-iphone-application-development/id473757255) course; Updated for XCode 4 and iOS 5.
- [Fall 2013-2014](http://online.stanford.edu/course/developing-ios7-apps-fall-2013) course is now available; Updated for XCode 5 and iOS 7.
- [Developing iOS 8 Apps with Swift](https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/developing-ios-8-apps-swift/id961180099).

Comment: Yeah, I forgot all about that till just a while ago. They have new classes all the time. Great stuff!

Answer (score 4):

There will be a second, new edition of Joe  Conway and Aaron Hillegass's book - iOS Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide, coming out at the end of June, 2011.  It will cover Xcode 4.0, the new Xcode development environment.

There will also be new editions of Cocoa Programming and Advanced MacOS X programming, along with new books for "More Cocoa programming" and Objective C coming out later this summer.  They would have been out sooner, but they had to wait for Apple to release Xcode 4 and go through review during classes at Big Nerd Ranch.

BNR is a great learning experience, if you get the chance to go out to Atlanta.  It's not just for programming, a lot of great networking with people.  Also they have their own B&B campus!

Answer (score 0):

I've been through a lotta books lately and i honestly feel that the best book out there is :

Head First iPhone Development -- A Learner's Guide to Creating Objective-C Applications for the iPhone (Second Edition)
By Dan Pilone, Tracey Pilone
Publisher: O'Reilly Media

It's an awesome book. They have a very innovative way of teaching you and taking you through the basics all the way to the advanced stuff. They expect you to physically think about what you're doing and practice too.

All in all, this is the best book out there for a beginner :D

Comment: I agree for beginner; but since he already knows how to program,  there is a lot of skipped pages.